# Не работают тесты (TestNG) web-приложение java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-ee, testng

Я только учусь, не судите строго за вопрос, а еще лучше - помогите. Сборка gradle. Сконфигурировал connection pool и hibernate в applicationcontext.xml spring(в этом же файле и описаны параметры подключения к базе данных). При развертывании на сервере все работает, но тесты стали failed(nullPointerException, так как session = null), что необходимо сделать чтобы в тестовый класс попадали параметры подключения к тестовой базе данных(sessionfactory был autowired при выполнении теста и следовательно session не была пустой)?
структура проекта:

```
src-main-java-MySqlDaoFactory.java
        -resources-conn.properties
        -webapp-WEB-INF-applicationcontext.xml
   -test-java-MySqlDaoFactoryTest.java
        -resources-testng.xml
```

тест:

```
    package students;
    import students.*;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import static org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    public class MySqlDaoFactoryTest {
    static MySqlDaoFactory daoFactory;
    @BeforeClass
    static void initAll() {
        daoFactory = new MySqlDaoFactory();
    }
    @Test
    void connectionTest() throws DAOException {
        Session session = daoFactory.getSession();
        assertNotNull(session, "Connection failed");
    }
}
```

класс который тестирую:

```
public class MySqlDaoFactory{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;
    public Session getSession() throws DAOException {
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("Error of session", e);
        }
        return session;
    }
}
```

testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="1" name="DAOTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="MySqlDaoFactoryTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

applicationcontext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     ....
    default-autowire="byName">
    <context:component-scan base-package="students" />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:conn.properties" />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}"/>
  <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
  <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="MySqlDaoFactory" class="MySqlDaoFactory">
    </bean>
    <bean id="session" class="MySqlDaoFactory"
    factory-bean="MySqlDaoFactory" factory-method="getSession">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: покажите весь класс . MySqlDaoFactoryTest

Comment: готово, указал все импорты. Класс сам по себе маленький (учебный)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны указать откуда брать контекст, чтобы Spring понимал, как инжектить данные.

Для Unit-тестов отделяют основной app_context и test_context. Для этого над тестовым классом нужно указать откуда брать нужный вам контекст. 
Для этого в спринге есть `@TestPropertySource`, который позволяет подгрузить указанный контекст.

Для вашего случая будет примерно так

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BaseTestConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource(value = "classpath:applicationcontext_test.xml")
public class MySqlDaoFactoryTest {
```

создаете в ресурсах `applicationcontext_test.xml` и настраиваете, скажем, *in mem db h2*

Comment: спасибо) правильно понимаю, что applicationcontext_test.xml будет выглядеть примерно также как и applicationcontext.xml(за исключением используемой базы данных)?

Comment: да, все верно. примерно одинаковы будут